# Problem importing KML generated with geotools into qgis

Tags: qgis, gdal, kml, geotools

I have a problem importing an kml 2.1 file generated with geotools 17.1 into qgis 2.8.

Qgis refuses to import, google earth imports it and if I save it in google earth qgis is willing to import it.

ogrinfo says:

```
 ogrinfo test.kml 
 ERROR 4: ERROR Parseing kml test.kml :Invalid root element
 ERROR 4: ERROR Parseing kml test.kml :Invalid root element
```

after saving it with google earth:

```
 ogrinfo test-ge.kml 
 INFO: Open of `test-ge.kml'
       using driver `LIBKML' successful.
 1: test-ge
```

This is the kml generated by geottols

```
 <kml:kml xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:kml="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
      <kml:Document id="featureCollection">
          <kml:Placemark id="guuid.27bed6fb-02ba-4536-8710-914fac29e236">
              <kml:name>"Grünliches etwas"</kml:name>
              <kml:description>DE-BB-Onlineeingabe null 2017-06-07
              </kml:description>
              <kml:Point>
                  <kml:coordinates>10.000000001438014,52.99999999818237
                  </kml:coordinates>
              </kml:Point>
          </kml:Placemark>            
      </kml:Document>
  </kml:kml>
```

This is the kml after saving it in google-eart:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <Document id="featureCollection">
         <name>test.kml</name>
         <Placemark id="guuid.27bed6fb-02ba-4536-8710-914fac29e236">
                 <name>&quot;Grünliches etwas&quot;</name>
                 <description>DE-BB-Onlineeingabe null 2017-06-07</description>
                 <Point>
                         <coordinates>10.00000000143801,52.99999999818237,0</coordinates>
                 </Point>
         </Placemark>
 </Document>
 </kml>
```

If I remove the namespace from the getools variant ogrinfo and qgis excepts it.

Is the namespace really invalid in kml? Or is gdal/orginfo/qgis to strict?

**EDIT**

here is the code used:

```
@Override
public void export(Collection<Occurrence> occurrences, OutputStream os)
{
  SimpleFeatureCollection features = createSampleFeatures(occurrences, false);
  Encoder encoder = new Encoder(new KMLConfiguration());
  encoder.setIndenting(true);
  try
  {
 encoder.encode(features, KML.kml, os);
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
 String message = "Failure to encode KMLConfiguration.";
 throw new FloradbException(FloradbError.INTERNAL_ERROR, message + e);
  }
}

protected SimpleFeatureCollection createSampleFeatures(
 Collection<Occurrence> occurrences, boolean withLink)
{
  SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder typeBuilder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
  typeBuilder.setName("occurrences");
  typeBuilder.add("geometry", Geometry.class, DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
  typeBuilder.add("name", String.class);
  typeBuilder.add("description", Object.class);
  SimpleFeatureType type = typeBuilder.buildFeatureType();

  SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(type);
  List<SimpleFeature> simpleFeatures = new ArrayList<>();
  CoordinateTransformerFactory factory = new CoordinateTransformerFactory();

  Iterator<Occurrence> iterator = occurrences.iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext())
  {
 Occurrence occurrence = iterator.next();
 String wkt;
 if (occurrence.getSample().getPosition().getWktEpsg() == 4326)
 {
    wkt = occurrence.getSample().getPosition().getWkt();
 }
 else
 {
    CoordinateTransformer transformer = factory
      .getCoordinateTransformer(
        occurrence.getSample().getPosition().getWktEpsg(),
        4326);
    wkt = transformer
      .convert(occurrence.getSample().getPosition().getWkt());
 }

 WKTReader wktReader = new WKTReader();
 try
 {
    Geometry geom = wktReader.read(wkt);
    featureBuilder.add(geom);
 }
 catch (ParseException e)
 {
    String message = "Failure to convert wkt to Geometrie.";
    throw new FloradbException(FloradbError.INTERNAL_ERROR,
      message + e);
 }
 featureBuilder.add(occurrence.getTaxon().getName());
 String link;
 if(withLink)
 {
    link = "<a href=\"http://" + homeUrl + "/#!quellendetails//"
         + occurrence.getSample().getSurvey().getId() + "\">"
         + occurrence.getSample().getSurvey().getTitle() + "</a>";
 }
 else
 {
    link = occurrence.getSample().getSurvey().getTitle();
 }
 featureBuilder
       .add(link + " "
         + StringFormatter.getNullSafeStringRepresentation(
           occurrence.getSample().getSurvey().getAvailability())
         + " " + occurrence.getSample().getDate() + " Fund-UUID: "
         + occurrence.getUuid());
 simpleFeatures.add(featureBuilder
       .buildFeature("uuid." + occurrence.getUuid().toString()));
  }

  return DataUtilities.collection(simpleFeatures);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you delete the double quotas around the kml:name in the GeoTools variant?

Comment: @user30184 the same error - i've also removed the german umlaut

Comment: can you add the code you used to write it?

Comment: This is weird as both GDAL/OGR and GoogleEarth are using the same LIbKML (in theory)

Comment: I can also confirm that the other KML driver can't read files with a kml: namespace either

Comment: The namespace [http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1](http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1) does not exist. But that isn't the problem.

Comment: I am a college of dve, the code we are using is: @Override public void export(Collection<Occurrence> occurrences, OutputStream os) { SimpleFeatureCollection features = createSampleFeatures(occurrences, false); Encoder encoder = new Encoder(new KMLConfiguration()); encoder.setIndenting(true); try { encoder.encode(features, KML.kml, os); } catch (IOException e) { String message = "Failure to encode KMLConfiguration."; throw new FloradbException(FloradbError.INTERNAL_ERROR, message + e); } } protected SimpleFeatureCollection createSampleFeatures( Collection<Occurrence> occurrences, boolean withLi

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in the OGR KML drivers - I've raised a [bug](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6981).

**UPDATE** This is fixed in GDAL 2.2.2

In the meantime a temporary work around is to remove the `kml:` from the output.

```
SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection = DataUtilities.collection(list);

Encoder encoder = new Encoder(new KMLConfiguration());
encoder.setIndenting(true);
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
  encoder.encode(featureCollection, KML.kml, os );
  String out = os.toString().replaceAll("kml:", "");
  System.out.println(out);
} catch (Exception e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```